# Dom item is not shown after ajax call unless i resize window

Tags: jquery, laravel-4, bxslider

I am creating page with laravel 4 and I have strange problem - DOM is not shown. On localhost it works fine, but if I check the page on server - DOM is not shown unless i resize window (then it suddenly appears).

```
$('#gallery li .overlay').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!$(this).hasClass('current')) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#gallery li .overlay').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        $('#single').slideUp(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET"
            }).done(function (json) {
                    $('#single').html(json);

                    if ($(window).width() > 768)
                        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                            pager: false
                        });
                    else
                        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
                            pager: false,
                            controls: false
                        });

                    window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", url);

                    $('#single').slideDown();
                });
        });
    }
});
```

Link to website: http://goo.gl/5OMlxh

Answer (score 0):

Hey may be this is happening because of rendering issue so please hide the page and than show after some time may be it's work

ex

```
$("#outerDivid").hide();
setTimeout(function(){
$("#outerDivid").show();
},10);
```

put this code after adding data of ajax in dom

Answer (score 0):

jQuery SlideUp() and SlideDown() functions breaks your DOM, thats why it was not working properly